# change an image with a p:commandButton click

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```html
<h:form>  
            <p:dataTable var="btsEvent" value="#{eventController.eventsList}" rows="5"
                         paginator="true"
                         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
                <p:column id="Acknowledged" headerText="Acknowledged" >
                    <!-- conditional rendering -->
                    
                    <p:graphicImage id="#{btsEvent.id}" value="resources/elements/confirm.png" rendered="#{btsEvent.ack}" /> 
                    
                    
                    <p:commandButton value="OK" id="AckButton" rendered="#{!btsEvent.ack}" 
                                     actionListener="#{btsEvent.getAcknowledgedOnClick(btsEvent.id)}" 
                                     styleClass="ui-priority-primary"/>
                    
                </p:column>
                
                
                
                </p:dataTable>
            
            
        </h:form>
```

1. I'm trying to assign a dynamic id to graphicImage in order to be able to catch it later with javascript and change its source attribute via **btsEvent.getAcknowledgedOnClick(btsEvent.id)**. It seems that making dynamic id is not available here since I get "**Empty id attribute is not allowed**". 
   My goal is to reneder an OK image or a confirmation button that when clicked some code is executed and then another js code changes the image. 
   How do I assign dynamic id to the image or access  corresponding **graphicImage** from **getAcknowledgedOnClick** function?
2. Other option is to have the button itself renedered as an image and change that image in code. How can I do that?

Comment: Let it have a 'static' id. Add a dynamic class to it and use that class value to select the image afterwards

Comment: What object does the btsEvent point to? Does the class of the object have "id" attribute? Does it hold value for all the objects?